# cannot find reference of "keras" and "to_categorical": from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Im using pycharm version: 17.0.4.1+7-b469.62 amd64 and python 3.9, the tensorflow version is 2.11.0. anyone here can help me with this problem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ie5Ev.png)

Is there anyone can help me..
OS:Windows 10 btw

Comment: Sometimes, pycharm is not telling the truth. Have you actually tried to run it? do you get an error message?

Comment: Please tell us the output of `import keras` `keras.__version__` to understand the error and fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

For both the issues,

Please update your VS Code to accommodate 64-bit Python version as it is the only one supported in Tensorflow.

Here is the official [reference](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) for it.